# problem loading internet pages

Tags: internet, dns, dhcp

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 and when on firefox i can get onto google or google earth and even gmail.But it wont connect to amazon or ebay or bbc or itv homepage.It only seems to like google I have ethernet connection.I also cant download from download centre Yet downloaded google chrome no probs.  Weird

Comment: what happens when you ping?  By this I mean, type at the terminal: `ping -c5 amazon.com`  where you can replace amazon.com by any other website.  You should get a response back from Amazon and everywhere else.  If you don't, then it's a general Internet connecitivy issue, not a Firefox issue.

Comment: ok I ping amazon and ebay .I got back  5 packets transmitted,0 received,100% packet loss

Comment: does this mean anything to you ?

Comment: Yes.  `ping` has nothing to do with Firefox, so this means the issue is with your general Internet setup.  I would guess your DHCP is not configured correctly.  You're connected directly by ethernet, not through a router, right?  What's your ip?

Comment: Oh, and try the ping with google.com.  From what you said, you should get packets received back, but let's make sure.

Comment: If you can't connect to anything other than google, how are you on askUbuntu exactly?

Comment: @dobey There are ways of connecting to AskUbuntu without using a computer you installed 11.10 on.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh But it is best not to assume them, or that Ubuntu is itself the problem. There are many unanswered clues to what is wrong, and everyone so far is grasping at random straws. How is it that only Google is working? Does he have a proxy? Does different computer on same network work properly? If so, what are the differences in network configuration between them?

Comment: Hi. I am managing to speak on here only because i have a laptop connected wirelessly and on windows XP.

Comment: I also did the ping with google and received the correct reply so I am now in the process of phoning my ISP. But as it is Virgin I dont suppose they will be much help as they probably only support windows :)

Comment: also I dont believe Ubuntu is the problem as it has worked fine before.I will let you know what my ISP says. Thanks for your help Chan-hosuh

Comment: Ok guys.Just spoke with isp who tells me everything is good their end. Its NOT dns as that works fine on laptop.I am connedcted through ethernet but also via a router which is my modem and router all in one. I am served by Virgin Media and they say to ask how to clear cookies and temp files on linux as they think this may be the problem.

Comment: THANKS GUYS you are awesome. Looked at first like Dobey was right but my ISP all checks good.It seems to be down to a problem with my machine as when i reloaded ubuntu it took 6HOURS to install.Ive taken sais PC to the repair shop LOL

Comment: Hi David, glad to hear *this* ordeal has been resolved.  Best of luck with your repair!

Comment: Hey Guys Just in case anyone is interested for future reference >>>>after all that it turned out to be..........My ethernet cable was broken in some way. Thanks for all your help.Im now up and running

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to call your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which are open google servers. Because I think that there is something messed up at your ISP, and that is why google chrome works, because it uses these by default.

This can be set in network manager, in the upper right corner.

UPDATE: Not exactly in the corner, but a little left.

You can also edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and add the `nameserver 8.8.8.8` line.

Comment: Sorry but all I have in upper right corner is system settings,displays,etc I cant download anything from ubuntu software centre either.But I can connect to youtube and googleI.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the network indicator, and it is not in the corner, but a little left. OR also you can open the system settings and select the network. Here you select the settings which will open a new window. Select your connection and click edit, then switch to the IPV4 tab, where you can change the settings. I will also add the command line method.

Comment: Ok I went into network.nowhere does it say settings.It tells me I am WIRED and connected through auto ethernet then gives speed ip address etc.I know i am connected to internet just cant get anything other than google .Sorry But thanks for your advice .

Comment: Then do open a terminal and write `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` there in a new line. And save, and exit.

Comment: ok... done that   the nameserver i have there is 194.168.4.100   when I put in 8.8.8.8 line came up  "attempting to set the permissions of /root/.local    but failed.no such file or directory

Comment: I don't know what is the problem, because I can save it on my computer.

Comment: 194.168? are you sure about the 194?

Comment: try using `nano` instead of `gedit` to edit the file.

Comment: yes 194 I am connected to Virgin Media UK and they tell me all the settings are right and it is a fault with my computor itself.  Its in the workshop :(:(

Answer (score 0):

I once had that especially images from CDNs were not loading.

The solution for me was setting the DNS setting to `192.168.1.3`. (I don't know why exactly `.1.3`)

You can do this by go

`Network Connections → Edit a connection → IPv4 Settings → DNS Server`

Comment: Also try `ping amazon.com` in the terminal. First response should be `PING amazon.com (72.21.194.1) 56(84) bytes of data.`, with the IP address.