# Problem in Loading certain Websites in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: internet, browser

I have a DSL connection in Ubuntu 11.04 and am having problems loading content from certain websites(such as heroku.com, ubuntuforums.org) mostly providing CDN services, though google and gmail run perfectly.

I have tried every suggestion asked at [problem loading internet pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121806/problem-loading-internet-pages) as I have the same problem. Also tried to remove the DNS Cache and Browser Cache.

I have tried using Google DNS Server: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but nothing seems to work. Though when I browse the websites in Windows XP then it does not pose any problem.

This problem has come up only few days ago and has affected every browser(Chrome, Firefox and Opera) in Ubuntu 11.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have even updated my Chrome to the latest stable version.

Comment: Can you comment on which websites you have this problem with?

Comment: heroku.com, other websites loading content from s7.addthis.com, and almost every CDN service..

Comment: Though I get the following response from heroku.com on command line  `64 bytes from ec2-50-19-85-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com (50.19.85.156): icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=313 ms`

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'having problems loading content'? Maybe upload a screendump of what you see?

Comment: What I get is just the title of the page along with the loading screen.. saying **Connected to heroku.com** for some time and after that it says Page cannot not be loaded..

Comment: I had an obscure problem with [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) sizes, and changing them fixed it. 'sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1400' in terminal and the problem page worked immediately. I did a blog post [here](http://www.tomandshirley.com/2011/08/customs-caesar-ii-site-problems-solved.html) if you want more detail, but testing the above command is all you really need to try. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Tom: No luck with this command, tried with ppp0 also.

Comment: Do you have the problem with all browser extensions temporarily disabled? Or, are you using a hosts file to block content?

Comment: I have also tried disabling all extensions, even uninstalled them in Chrome.. still no progress

Comment: Maybe it's something your ISP has done? Could you talk with them or someone else using the same ISP?

Comment: The problem is not with ISP because I am able to view all these sites in Window XP and my friend(with Ubuntu 11.04 only) was able to view these sites with my net connection on his laptop.

Comment: I think google DNS was the culprit , can you try with the DNS provdied by ISP ?

Answer (score 2):

I suffered this exact same fate, and also couldn't find anything on how to fix it. I did finally get it to work, and wrote a blog post titled [Facebook, Youtube, LinkedIn and other CSS and JavaScript files from CDNs not loading on Ubuntu](http://ironzebra.com/news/49/facebook-youtube-linkedin-and-other-css-and-javascript-files-from-cdns-not-loading-on-ubuntu) that explains the process I went through and things I tried.

In short, the solution was to create a manual connection to the router (i.e. not Automatic DHCP), with a custom DNS server. This is done by right-clicking on the connections icon -> `Edit connections...` -> `Edit` -> `IP4 Settings`. I used `8.8.8.8` as Primary DNS, but it could be anything other than the IP of the router, that is the default. The important thing here is that I'm circumventing the router when it comes to DNS traffic, as opposed to simply setting a different DNS server on the router itself.